# xpath to get rows inside a table

Tags: java, xpath

I have a html table like:

```
<table ..... class="cars">

<tr class="item-odd">
...
</tr>
<tr class="item-even">
</tr>

</table>
```

How could I get the table rows using xpath?

```
//tr[contains(@class, ???)
```

can I use OR in there somehow to say item-odd|item-even

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the rows like this:

```
//table[@class='cars']/tr
```

To get the item-odd rows, you would do this:

```
//table[@class='cars']/tr[@class='item-odd']
```

Yes, you can use `or`, e.g.:

```
//table[@class='cars']/tr[@class='item-odd' or @class='item-even']
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath for more details.

Comment: This fails nowadays since browsers silently add a tbody to the path. So it needs to be more like `//table[@class='cars']/tbody/tr`