# Can't get Cucumber script to pass when trying to follow a link in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

I am using Rails 3 with Cucumber, Capybara and Factory_Girl.  I am trying to test following the "Show" link for just one of the rows on an HTML table.  I am using the syntax:

```
And I follow "Show" within "Net 30"
```

I gives me the following error:

```
unexpected '30' after 'DESCENDANT_SELECTOR' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/racc/parser.rb:99:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/racc/parser.rb:99:in `__send__'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/racc/parser.rb:99:in `do_parse'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/view_payment_terms.feature:10:in `And I follow "Show" within "Net 30"'
```

Here is the full Cucumber script that fails:

```
Feature: View Payment Terms
  In order to view payment terms
  As a user
  I want to view payment terms

    Scenario: View Payment Terms
      Given there is a payment term named "Net 30"
      And there is a payment term named "Net 60"
      When I go to the "payment terms screen"
      And I follow "Show" within "Net 30"
      Then I should see "Terms description: Net 30"
```

If I change that line to just say:

```
And I follow "Show"
```

It passes with no errors.  I looked in the web_steps.rb that came with Capybara and what I am using appears to be correct:

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |link, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    click_link(link)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Cucumber wants a valid XPath selector there. Try writing an XPath query that will select the TR containing a cell with the text "Net 30" in it. This link may help: [xpath to get rows inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017119/xpath-to-get-rows-inside-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri is throwing an error at the CSS selector `Net 30` because, of course, it's not a valid CSS selector. I think you're looking for an element whose *text* is "Net 30", which is very different.